# Django test counting queries is failing because of SQL EXPLAIN queries

Tags: django, postgresql, pytest, psycopg2, pytest-django

I have a test like this:

```py
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTestClass(TestCase):
    def test_query_count(self):
        with self.assertNumQueries(12):
            some_service_call()
```

When running tests using pytest I get an error saying that there were 24 queries instead of 12 and when checking the logged error I see that I have one EXPLAIN query per real query made by `some_service_call()`.
This is not happening with plain django test runner (i.e: `python manage.py test`).

Does anyone know why I'm getting these explain queries and how can I avoid getting them when testing? I'm using the official postgresql docker image.

Weird thing is that when I run using pytest for that file (i.e: `pytest path/to/test.py`) I don't have this issue.

Comment: Is the docker image configuring [auto-explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/auto-explain.html)?

Comment: I used the plain docker image. I tried to check what you mention but wasn't able to confirm if this was on or off. I think it is off by default. Do you know how to check it and set it off in case it is on?

Comment: Ok, I think I found the issue. Will confirm later but I was accidentally using a Django setting I use to do profiling. In that setting I'm adding django-silk and django-slow-tests test runner. One of those must be setting the auto_explain option in postgres. I'll check which one is causing it, although I'm positive it is django-silk